# PHP function that auto imports all CSS files from a certain directory

Tags: php, html, css, function

I'm working on a website that has 6 CSS files at the moment. I want to make a php function that scans a directory and load all the CSS files in de HTMl head. I got this working on the index page, but as soon as I go to another page it doesn't work. This is because it's searching for the CSS folder from an different location. To be clear, In the root folder I have a file called Header.php, index.php and Footer.php . The header.php file contains the HTML head and the navigation bar/menu at the top of the website. The header.php is loaded in every page with this line

```
require "header.php";
```

The file path changes on a higher laying page, for example the one on in the "About Us" page look like this

```
require "../../header.php";
```

I can solve the problem bye making the function for every sup directory, but this isn't the correct way to do it (at least I think).
This is my current php function:

```
function css(){
    $css = glob("CSS/*.css");
    $css_out = "";
    foreach($css as $css_path){
        $css_out .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css_path.'">'; 
    }
    return $css_out;
}
```

I have this at the top of the page just bereave the require header

```
$css_web = css();
```

I load the actual data with

```
 <?php echo $css_web?>
```

Comment: "it's searching for the CSS folder from an different location"...you can get PHP to tell you the path of the current script / URL (check out the various $_SERVER values in the docs) and then you can construct an appropriate relative path from that for your stylesheet folder.

Comment: If `CSS/` is in the root of the site then `"/CSS/*.css"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute URL instead of relative URL.

Replace

```
$css_out .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css_path.'">';
```

with

```
//$assets_url = "http://example.com/assets/css/";
$css_out .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$assets_url.'.'.$css_path.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Go one better, and remove the need for any further requests!

Loop through the files, grab the contents, and echo it into a `<style>` block!

```
$css = glob("CSS/*.css");
$css_out = '<style>';

foreach($css as $css_path){
    $style = file_get_contents($css_path);
    $css_out .= $style; 
}

return $css_out . '</style>;
```

Then just echo it in your head :-D

To keep paths correct, you can use `__DIR__` which gives you the directory of the file you are in :-), and you can get absolute paths by passing that into `realpath()`